# Как мне подключить jQuery через functions.php в админке?

Tags: wordpress

Я на одном [сайте](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/) установил плагин BJ Lazy Load. Но после его установки пропали миниатюры в админке при просмотре всех записей. Как мне подключить jQuery через functions.php в админке?

Answer (score 1):

можно написать функцию, которая добавляет в хэдер строку `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-файл"></script>`

Comment: @kstv конечно, можно, но это неправильно с точки зрения логики Wordpress